# Firebase App Distribution get registered tester's UDID

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

Is there any way to get registered tester's UDID. We deleted wrongly mail which comes from Firebase accidentally. Before Firebase App Distribution, we can find it in Fabric Beta. But now we can not access directly to UDID.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chintan from Firebase. We don't expose that currently in the dashboard. The tester could find their UDID in the App Distribution webclip's settings and email that back to you (we show it on the "Manage account" page). Or you can delete the tester and re-add them to your app. Then the tester would have to accept the invite again, consent their device, then register their profile and you'd receive the email again.

Comment: Are you planning on implementing it via API? It would be handy for CI environments to check if new testers with their UDIDs were added and update provisioning profiles accordingly before uploading build to app distribution

Comment: BTW should I file a feature request for that here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features?

Comment: Yes, you can add submit a feature request by following that link

Comment: In the current version of the App Distribution app clip the UDID is truncated on smaller devices like an iPhone 7.  This makes it impossible to get the UDID from App Distribution in these cases.

Comment: See new answer below - tester UDIDs can now be bulk exported from the Firebase console.

Also @MelStanley - thanks for the feedback, the UDID is now visible on smaller devices.

Answer (score 5):

All tester UDIDs can now be exported to a CSV from the Testers & Groups tab of the App Distribution dashboard. This file can then be imported into the Apple developer console. See the [Register additional devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/ios/distribute-console#register-tester-devices) instructions for more info.